# Subprocess.check_output doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

When I use the check_output within the Subprocess module I have this output error from the Python shell:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

The code:

```
target = raw_input("IP: ")
port = subprocess.check_output(["python", "portscanner.py", target ])
```

I use Python 2.7. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: What does `print subprocess.__file__` say is the location of the module? Also `.check_output()` was only added in Python 2.7, so make triple sure you are running the correct Python version.

Answer (score 1):

check_output() method is defined in python2.7 onwards, as said by "Martijn Pieters"

check in subprocess.py line no: 515

```
def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
```

you may either be using the old python version or you might have messed up with the python interpreter.

try using

```
dir(module[.class])
```

to find the available methods or classes in any module and proceed.